# Turing Machine that triples a unary format number?

Tags: turing-machines

I managed to figure out how to double a unary format number however I have had no such success in tripling it. An input tape would be of the following format Λ111Λ and the output would be like Λ111Λ111111111Λ with the tripled number coming directly after the initial input tape. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the number once (as you have done already). Mark the spot between the original and the copy with a new letter. Now run again the copy, but stop copying once you see the letter $\land$.

That is, copy $\land 111\land$ into $\land 111 \#  111 \land $. Now copy again, while thinking of $\#$ as the new beginning of the tape. You will get $\land 111 \# 111 \# 111 \land$. After that, replace all $\#$ with $\land$ to get: $\land 111\land 111\land 111\land$

Notice that this process can be done any number of times, meaning that you can clone the input any number of times you would like!

---

Also, as a general "trick" for such problems, try introducing either a new letter to the alphabet (it usually helps create edge cases that you need to solve), or to meddle with an existing machine's states (such as adding an index into their states, etc')

Comment: That does make sense thanks, I tried running it again using your method but I ended up creating a machine that doesn't halt, I will try fix this thanks.

Comment: I don't suppose you have an example definition of a machine to this problem?

Comment: add an index $k$ into your states to know at which clone you are doing now.